# 'Reverse' derive correct dataset from just mean and std dev?

Tags: excel, statistics

If I know the mean and standard deviation, but I don't have an original data set, is it possible to reverse calculate a data set that has this known mean and std dev? Is there an excel function I could use to do this easily?

I am aware that I can use "=norminv(rand(), MEAN, ST.DEV)" in Excel to give me a normal distribution of random numbers that may each individually fit a given mean and std. dev. but when taken together as a group, this data set never gives me the correct mean and std dev.

So, for a MEAN = 100 and STD. DEV= 15, can anyone tell me how to calculate a data set with n=4 that will have this mean and std dev?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Brent, I've tried to use "=norminv(rand(), MEAN, ST.DEV)" in Excel and the "normrnd" function in Matlab. Both will give me what looks to be a random set of values that would fit into a normal distribution for a given mean and std dev. but when taken together as a combined data set, they don't give have the corret mean/std dev. That's a far as I've got at the moment.

Comment: you could use norminv to generate n-2 variables, and solve the last 2 variables to get the mean and std you want

Answer (score 1):

Four numbers that average `100` must sum to 400, so given three numbers the fourth has to be 400 less the sum of the other three. Calculate the standard deviation for all four numbers and then use Goal Seek to adjust one of the three to give `15` for the result of the standard deviation formula.